# CSS clip: unset; on Safari

Tags: css, wordpress, safari, clip

I'm writing CSS in WordPress for a fullscreen background image.
To get rid of a black rectangle to the left (menu/sidebar), I'm using the CSS below.

It's working fine in chrome, IE and on mobile, but not working on **mac/safari**.

How do I write this code so it works on Safari?

```
.mk-page-section .background-clipper {
    clip: unset;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I write just "auto" it doesn't work in any browser, the black rectangle is there. 
In Chrome/IE the "unset" seem to fix the problem.

```
.mk-page-section .background-clipper {
  clip: auto;
}
```

or:

```
.mk-page-section .background-clipper {
  clip: rect(auto, auto, auto, auto);
}
```

Any idea how to fix this on Safari? -webkit?

/T

Answer (score 0):

Safari on macOS supports the `unset` value from version 9.1 and later.

In any case, using `unset` is unnecessary here. The initial value of `clip` is `auto`, so just write `clip: auto`.